# Exception when trying to migrate zend files to local host

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, exception, localhost

I'm trying to run a php zend files from a server to local host (migrate). I've change the configuration that i know of but when I try to run it, the error below shows up in the browser;

```
Array ( [0] => Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception Object 
   ( 
   [message:protected] => Invalid controller specified (www) 
   [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 
   [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\www\html\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php 
   [line:protected] => 241 
   [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
            [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\www\html\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php 
            [line] => 936 
            [function] => dispatch 
            [class] => Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard 
            [type] => -> [args] => Array ( 
                 [0] => Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( 
                     [_paramSources:protected] => Array ( 
                         [0] => _GET [1] => _POST ) 
                         [_requestUri:protected] => /www/html/web/ 
                         [_baseUrl:protected] => 
                         [_basePath:protected] => 
                         [_pathInfo:protected] => /www/html/web/ 
                         [_params:protected] => Array ( 
                             [controller] => www 
                             [action] => html 
                             [module] => default 
                             )
                         [_aliases:protected] => Array ( ) 
                         [_dispatched:protected] => 1 
                         [_module:protected] => default 
                         [_moduleKey:protected] => module 
                         [_controller:protected] => www 
                         [_controllerKey:protected] => controller 
                         [_action:protected] => html 
                         [_actionKey:protected] => action 
                     ) 
                 [1] => Zend_Controller_Response_Http Object ( 
                     [_body:protected] => Array ( ) 
                     [_exceptions:protected] => Array RECURSION 
                     [_headers:protected] => Array ( ) 
                     [_headersRaw:protected] => Array ( ) 
                     [_httpResponseCode:protected] => 200 
                     [_isRedirect:protected] => 
                     [_renderExceptions:protected] => 
                   [headersSentThrowsException] => 1 
                 )
            )
       ) 
       [1] => Array ( 
           [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\www\html\index.php 
           [line] => 5 
           [function] => dispatch 
           [class] => Zend_Controller_Front 
           [type] => -> 
           [args] => Array ( ) 
       )
   )
   [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
)
```

Can u guys help me with this error? thanks in advance

Comment: if you migrate from windows to a linux system case of words can be an issue. Make sure your calling the controller with the same case it was defined.

Comment: Have you checked the php error log. That might be more use.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the exception says pretty much what the error log has to say in this case

Comment: this is from windows to windows, just from previous developer to me. I need to run it locally to make changes to the files.

Comment: did you make any changes in this file windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: no i did not. what should i look for to change there ?

Comment: @DevZer0 true, the error log only shows the exception from previous issue, not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the end of that file

`Host ip`  `localsite url`

For example

`127.192.220.12`   `zend.local`

I dunno sure it is the final solution.But it may help you!

Comment: It's not working. I just learn that this system is develop in linux. I want to migrate it to windows. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Alternatively you can write following line in [production] section of application.ini file: **resources.frontController.params.useDefaultControllerAlways = 1**

Comment: it doesn't change anything. I've read that this error is caused because of the controller not existing in the folder. I take this file and doesn't make any changes to the controller part. If its working live on the linux server, I just have no idea why it's not working on windows localhost. back to the internet then..